# On publishing a worker role to VM from visual studio 2012, will it start automatically?

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

Question 1: While publishing a worker role having while(true) block in its Run() method will it ensure that on successful completion of publish - the worker role will automatically start?

If no, then how to start it?

Question 2: If the worker role for some reason after starting has stooped - how to restart it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: While publishing a worker role having while(true) block in
>   its Run() method will it ensure that on successful completion of
>   publish - the worker role will automatically start?

Yes. All `Cloud Service` deployments start automatically. And your code shall **never** exit the `Run()` method. Should your code by any reason leave the `Run()` method, the role will be automatically `recycled`.

> Question 2: If the worker role for some reason after starting has
>   stooped - how to restart it?

The Windows Azure Fabric Controller takes care of such situations. There is way for a role to be stopped by `some reason`. The only way to [`suspend` a role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460808.aspx) (worker or web) is to explicitly require that from the Management API or the portal.

Check [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericgolpe/archive/2012/12/14/windows-azure-paas-role-instance-health-and-load-balancer-requests.aspx) for more info.